# Trying to add data to a database

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I'm trying to add data to a database with 3 columns and when I try to add multiple values I get the toast message that I created saying "Something went wrong" I know I'm doing something wrong, but I'm not sure. Here's the main activity which is having the error on all of the AddData methods

```
btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String newEntry = editText.getText().toString();
                String dateReleased=edtDateReleased.getText().toString();
                if (editText.length() != 0) {
                    AddData(newEntry,dateReleased);
                    editText.setText("");
                    edtDateReleased.setText("");
                } else {
                    toastMessage("You must put something in the text");
        btnViewData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListDataActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    public void AddData(String newEntry,String dateReleased) {
        boolean insertData = mDatabaseHelper.addData(newEntry,dateReleased);
        if (insertData) {
            toastMessage("Data Successfully Inserted!");
        } else {
            toastMessage("Something went wrong");
        }
    }
```

and here is the DatabaseHelper class

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                COL2 +" TEXT, "
                +COL3+" TEXT,"
                +COL4+" TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(createTable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean addData(String title,String dateReleased) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL2, title);
        contentValues.put(COL3,dateReleased);
        String fileName="/sdcard/"+title+".mpg";
        contentValues.put(COL4,fileName);


        Log.d(TAG, "addData: Adding " + title + " to " + TABLE_NAME);

        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

        //if date as inserted incorrectly it will return -1
        if (result == -1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should open connection first using the instance of your class

```
SQLiteDatabase db =this.getWritableDatabase();
this.onOpen(db);
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
contentValues.put("column_name", "column_value");
long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
db.close();
```